Finding a more efficient solution to chi-squared code
I have data y and x where y is some physical quantity and x is time. Both of these are arrays
The y data is dependent upon two parameters a and b and by simultaneously varying both of these and calculating the chi-squared for each combination, I can determine suitable values for a and b that fit the data.
My approach was to generate an array of a and b values within some min and max. Then iterate through these and calculate the chi-squared then find the combination with lowest chi-squared.
Is there a better way of doing this? It takes too long and I feel like there is a way around the iteration.
Thanks

What you are describing sounds like fairly standard least squares fitting. DIY codes for this tend to be slow and unreliable. There are plenty of libraries that can do this. If you show us a graph of the data it would be possible to provide a better answer. The usual method is to fit a model  y = F(x,a,b) and differentiate wrt a,b to get a matrix equation. Try fitting it in Excel or much steeper learning curve GnuPlot if you want a turnkey solution. The other way if the function is badly behaved is Golden mean optimisation search or as a last resort simplex or simulated annealing.
